# How to set the userAgent in a functional Test?

Tags: phpunit, symfony1, lime-unittest

I could not find any matching method in `sfTestFunctional` or `sfBrowser` to set the UserAgent string. Maybe it's not possible because it goes through php-cli?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$browser->setHttpHeader('User-Agent', 'some custom string')->get('your url')`
This sets the user agent for the next request, so maybe you want to extend the sfBrowser object to provide the HTTP headers on every request

Comment: Any idea how to do this outside of Symfony? I'm using Laravel and would also like to manually set the User Agent for tests.

Comment: I have never used Lavarel, but a quick google reveals `$this->call('GET', '/api', array(), array(), array("HTTP_USER-AGENT"=>"some string"));`. [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1655)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I wonder, what did you search for to find it? I searched a number of times and couldn't find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user371699 - "lavarel test set http header"